# VS 2011 template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

I have a rather standard situation where I want to use a templated class in the following way:

1. Define a .h file
2. Have it include the .cpp

In every other compiler that I try (i.e. g++ and clang/llvm) this works fine. In visual studio, it tells me that the file has already been defined.

If I manually cut and paste the text from the .cpp into the .h file, then everything works out just fine. I was under the impression that that was exactly what `#include` was supposed to do.

My hunch is that visual studio is compiling the .cpp file more than once somehow (though I placed `#pragma once` on the .h and .cpp files).

What is going on, and how can I make my template classes behave in VS?

Code follows:
**.h:**

```
#pragma once
template <class T>
class myVector
{
private:
    void grow();
public:
int size;
int index;
T** words;
void pushBack(T* data);
inline T* operator[](int);
myVector(void);
~myVector(void);
};

#include "myVector.cpp"
```

**.cpp:**

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include "myVector.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
myVector<T>::myVector(void)
{
    this->size = 2000;
    words = new T*[size];
    index=0;
}

template<class T>
void myVector<T>::pushBack(T* input)
{
    if(index<size)
    {
        words[index]=input;
    }
    else
    {
        grow();
        words[index]=input;
    }
    index++;
}

template<class T>
T* myVector<T>::operator[](int i)
{
    return words[i];
}

template<class T>
void myVector<T>::grow()
{
    //cout<<"I grew:"<<endl;
    size*=2;
    words = (T**)realloc(words,size*sizeof(T*));
}

template<class T>
myVector<T>::~myVector(void)
{
    delete[] words;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK it's considered bad practice to separate template declaration from definition. At a minimum, don't use .cpp, use .tpp. At best, define them where you declare them. It's less work for both you and the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your confusion arises from not knowing how `#pragma once` and translation units work.

`#pragma once`, much like include guards, prevent the contents of a file (usually a header) from being pulled into a single translation unit more than once.

If you `#include <vector>` in multiple implementation files, the contents will be pulled in all of them, but only once for each translation unit.

So you should remove the `#include "myVector.cpp"`, as MSVS automatically compiles implementation files, and it's also wrong.

Note that template definitions have to be visible, so you'll need to either move them to the `.h` file, like you did, or, using your current approach, rename the `.cpp` file to something like `.impl` or even `.h` and include it.

Comment: I am pretty confused. I am currently using `#include "myVector.h"` not `#include <vector>` If I remove the `#include "myVector.cpp"` then I get linker errors (see comment to other answer). And the extension of the file matters for VS? Changing the filename to myVector.impl works if I keep the include that is in the .h.

Comment: @soandos yes, the extension matters. The `#include <vector>` was just an example.